# Proper way to store encryption keys for use with multiple apps across multiple machines

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, encryption

Here is the scenario.

We have sensitive data such as SSN and DOB stored in our database.
This data is encrypted before we insert the record.

We have many (more than 20) application and web apps spanning multiple machines and datacenters that will need to either encrypt and store the data or retrieve and decrypt it. Most of the apps are .Net, but not all of them.

Currently we have a are using the Microsoft TrippleDESCryptoServiceProvide (we will be using a newer algorithm soon) to do the encryption/decryption.
We currently store the key inside the class we have that does the encryption/decryption.

This is obviously bad for multiple reasons that I'm sure we are all ware aware of. And before anyone chastises me, I didn't write this code, I inherited it.

In the end I need a central location where I can securely store the key and retrieve it quickly.

**Things to consider**

- Different types of apps (Console, windows forms, web sites and API's) need to access it
- Apps run on different machines, some are not part of the domain and are in a DMZ. Most are windows running .Net apps, but some run Linux and are GO apps.
- We do have a central DB server, but then how would we securely store the SQL credentials used to access the key?
- Running SQL server 2016 Pro.

Comment: Why are you encrypting the data?  Is to protect against database backups being stolen and the like, or do you have more application-based reasons for encrypting, such as to control access?

Comment: Backups are encrypted and put in cold storage so no concerns there. The issue is not having sensitive data human readable to anyone with query access.

Comment: Check this app out -- https://netlibsecurity.com/products/sql-server-encryption/ its transparent to the application layer.  Lets you encrypt data, and so one can read (aside from logins you grant access to decrypt).  If I recall correctly, this is done via a view sitting on the encrypted data and permissions control if a login can call the decryption methods or not; if not, the data is simply returned encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption) feature of SQL Server?

While it's not a key storage mechanism per se, if your goal is to protect the data "at rest" (i.e. in the database files on the filesystem and in all backups), then this may provide a way to do that without having your own encryption method split between the various applications.

TDE is not the most complicated thing to set up, but make sure you understand how the certificates and keys are used, and that you know what you need to back-up (and store securely) to be able to recover data and restore backups to different machines and the like.

It won't fix your distributed key issue, but you could either do away with the requirement to encrypt/decrypt the data into and out of the database in each application and have the database do it transparently.

As another alternative, you could also use a separate TDE-secured database on the central server as the store for your encryption key, which all the other applications can then access.

With TDE, you're correct in that anyone with credentials to the SQL Server would be able to access the data in plain-text, so you'd need to protect the credentials to the server, as you mentioned.

**Protecting Credentials**

As you have machines spread between different operating systems and domains, you probably need multiple different ways of protecting the credentials on each one (which I guess you know).

For Windows machines on the same domain as the SQL Server (or a domain trusted by the SQL Server), you can't really beat a [Group Managed Service Account](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/).  They are a domain-level account that cannot be interactively logged in, have a very long and periodically mutating password, and can only be used by service accounts.  With these, you don't need SQL account credentials because you can grant database permissions directly to the service account (the connection string uses "Integrated_Security=True").

For Windows machines not on the domain, a sensible way to store credentials is with the [Data Protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection).  With this, you can give the SQL Username and Password credentials to your code (running as some low-priviledge service user), which it then DPAPI protects and stores in a file.  That way, only code running as that service user would be able to read them back out.  Nefarious code accessing the filesystem from another user wouldn't be able to decrypt them.

As for Linux, that's not really my area, sorry.

**Certificates**

To throw even more food for thought in, all operating systems (well, at least Windows and Linux) have some way of protecting certificates and their private keys, and many frameworks (such as .NET) have methods for using certificates to encrypt and decrypt data.  You could potentially generate a certificate and private key (which gives you an Asymmetric key pair), and install them both on each on your servers.

With that, you can then generate a Symmetric key (for 3DES or AES, for example), then encrypt the Symmetric key with your certificate's Asymmetric public key.  The encrypted Symmetric key can be put in a central database or somewhere else.  Only applications with the asymmetric private key to decrypt the symmetric key would then be able to use it to decrypt the data.

Comment: Thanks for the post but this is not really what I am looking for. I need the data returned from queries to be encrypted so that eyes cannot see them. I have thought about storing the keys in the database, but then how do you securely store the SQL credentials?

Comment: @TRock Sorry, I was in the middle of the edit so I didn't see your comments.  I'll have a think and maybe post a separate answer with some suggestions more pertinent to your issue.

Comment: Interesting stuff here. Also one thing to note about the data Protection API is that we cannot store the credentials in code as it will be checked into a repository. I like the thought of using the group account to access the SQL server though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that well.  With DPAPI, I didn't mean the credentials would be stored in the source code.  I meant that after you install your appliction and get it running on the server, you would call a page or handler in the application into which you enter the credentials, and the application then DPAPI encrypts them and stores them into its config file or other storage.  That way even an administrator user can't decrypt them.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as the DPAPI is what I am going to use to store the keys while the app is running. I have decided to use either the Azure Key Vault or possibly another HSM to store the key. When the app needs the key for the first time it will reach out and get it.